# How can I set the spring-rabbitmq listener's rate of receive message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using spring-rabbitmq ,and I can get messages successfully.
but when I debug I found that the listener creates a thread and it will ask
for messages every 1 second .I think the rate is too high .what I want to do is to set the rate 1 min or any other.
I search a lot but does not works

My springrabbit.xml:

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"  message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" >
        <rabbit:listener queues="notification" ref="messageReceiver"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

my java code :

```
@Override
        public void onMessage(Message message)  { System.out.println("messagebody:   "+new String(message.getBody()));
            LOGGER.info(dateFormatUtil.getDateFormat(new Date())+new String(message.getBody()));
            boolean result=false;
            SendSingleEmailService sendSingleEmailService = new SendSingleEmailService();
            try {
                result =sendSingleEmailService.send(new String(message.getBody()));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                LOGGER.error(dateFormatUtil.getDateFormat(new Date())+"[NOTIFICATION] [ERROR] message is null!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(!result) {
                try{
                    throw new Exception();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }finally {
                    LOGGER.error(dateFormatUtil.getDateFormat(new Date())+"[NOTIFICATION] [ERROR] Send Email failed!");
                }
            }


        }
```

Some of debug results are as follows:

```
[2017-08-16 18:23:08,595]DEBUG  4286[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:09,600]DEBUG  5291[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:10,602]DEBUG  6293[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:11,603]DEBUG  7294[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:12,609]DEBUG  8300[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:13,612]DEBUG  9303[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:14,615]DEBUG 10306[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:15,617]DEBUG 11308[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:16,618]DEBUG 12309[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[2017-08-16 18:23:17,619]DEBUG 13310[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:186) - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5AR22lnMjmLAj329LDpGbQ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@192.168.203.151:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `receiveTimeout` - see [Message Listener Container Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#containerAttributes).

However, the container will be less responsive to `stop()` requests.

I think you are overly concerned about the polling rate - there is very little overhead to poll the internal queue used to stage delivered messages.

If it's just the log "noise" you want to remove (when debugging) set the `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer` log category to `INFO` or `WARN`.

The upcoming 2.0 release has a new `DirectMessageListenerContainer` which does not poll an internal queue and eliminates this issue. [Info here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_introduction.html#_new_listener_container).

**EDIT**

> listener still ask rabbitmq for messages every 1s

If you are still seeing the debug message every 1s, you have not configured the `receiveTimeout` properly; IT IS NOT "asking rabbitmq" for a message, the thread is waking up after waiting for `receiveTimeout` (and found that rabbit has not sent a new message) so it can react to a `stop()`; then it sleeps again until a new message arrives or it times out again. There is no interaction with the broker if no messages are available - messages are pushed by the broker.

Perhaps you are misunderstanding the purpose of the listener container. It is for message-driven applications - you can't "slow down" the rate that messages arrive - they are pushed by the broker.

If you want to receive a message only once a minute, you should use a `RabbitTemplate` `receive()` (or `receiveAndConvert()`) method instead of a message listener container.

Comment: Thanks ,I read the doc and tried  [receiveTimeout]  ,then I found it occurs only when I have received a message ,otherwise the listener still ask rabbitmq for messages every 1s . I want to set the listener ask for messages every 1 min.can <rabbit:listener-container>   do this? thanks.

Comment: omg,I misunderstanded it.thanks,I tried again with receiveAndConvert() and it works.